# Iterating through inputs and passing data to an AJAX function

Tags: javascript

I am looping through several inputs and trying to append that data into an object which I can then pass into an AJAX function.  I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong, but I keep getting an error that says `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"`, and I can't find this extra bracket, and I think I must just be doing this incorrectly.

```
var dataObject = [];

$("#"buttonId).find("input").each(function(index) {

    inputId = $(this).attr("id").replace(buttonId, "");
    inputValue = $(this).val();

    var data = { 
       inputId : inputValue;
    }

    dataObject.push(data);
});

$.post(
    'ajax/' + buttonId + '.php', 
    {
        dataObject: dataObject
    },
    function (response) {
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `+` for string concatenation.

```
$("#"buttonId)
//   ^----
```

Also you cannot use a variable as a property name in object literal, try this:

```
var data = {}; 
data[inputId] = inputValue;
dataObject.push(data);
```

You can also use `map` method:

```
var dataObject = $("#" + buttonId).find("input").map(function() {
    var inputId = this.id.replace(buttonId, ""),
        obj = {};
    obj[inputId] = this.value;
    return obj;
}).get();
```

Or [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method.

Comment: Yes, that seemed to work!  I will look at the map method and .serializeArray() method before continuing to make sure I have the best suited approach.  Thanks you so much for your help, and teaching me what I was doing wrong.